# Testing working of internal functions using nunit tests

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I have a function which calls many functions internally. I see in tutorials that test methods are designed in such a way that only the return values of outer functions are checked. How can I check the values returned by internal functions.

Only the `GetValues()` methods values are tested. How can i check the working of other methods inside  `GetValues()`. How can I check its working using unit testing?

```
[TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        public void Tester()
        {
            TesterClass clasObj;
            int a = clasObj.GetValues();
            Assert.AreEqual(10,a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would think the answer is obvious - if you care about the methods that `GetValues()` calls, then you write tests that test them, just as the code above tests `GetValues()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with some tools, like TypeMock, but there is a reason why most tools don't allow it.  This is because it usually makes the tests very brittle, meaning that when you change the internal code of a class, the tests will break.  Internal members should be encapsulated and that is a good thing. I would look at a design that is testable from its public interface.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i check its working using unit testing?

In unit tests you only care about the, well, the unit, under test. In this case it is the GetValues. Also, usually only the public methods are unit tested. Because it is only the public methods ( interface) that has to be tested and not the internal workings.

It also ensures that the tests are not brittle. If you change the way a private / internal method works, but will essentially make the public interfaces work the same ( this especially when you are using mocks, and not really in the kind of testing you are doing), you shouldn't really be facing failed unit tests.

In such cases, you should be making sure that your unit tests cover all code path through the public method being tested and the private / internal methods that are being called by the method under test.

Sometimes, you do want to test the internals and one way is to use the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` and mark the test assembly as a "friend".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Another way is to subclass the class you are testing ( possibly in your test assembly), and add a public wrapper method to the method to be tested and use this proxy class and the public wrapper for testing.

Comment: Just to add: InternalsVisibleToAttribute will allow you to see classes in another assembly marked as Internal.

Comment: Marking stuff as Internal to test while valid is a code smell IMO. You've got missing objects if you need to do this.

Comment: @Finglas - Did you miss rest of the answer and just read that line?

Comment: @manojlds nope. I agree with what you said, bar marking code as internal just to test it.

Comment: @Finglas - `bar marking code as internal just to test it` - I never said that. Read the question - `How can i check the values returned by *internal* functions.`

Comment: Uh, yes you did. You even linked to it on MSDN.

Comment: @manojlds the question asker is not talking about internal in terms of internal visibility. They are on about testing code inside public methods that cannot be accessed by the public interface. Indeed making methods internal and exposing them is one way to do this, but this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to avoid testing the internal implementations of code, this is so that you can refactor and not break any tests. However, if you want to test the inside of another object, then the answer is easy. By wanting to test private implementation, the code smell is that the current object under test is doing too much work. In turn violating such rules as the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Therefore split out GetValues into a new object that you can test, such as:

```
ExampleFormatter.FormatValues()
```

Now this would be a public class with a public method meaning you can easily test it. All `GetValues` has to do now is invoke `FormatValues` with the correct params. You could use a [mock object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) to verify that this happens as expected. As this is now public, when can test such things as the formatting of the values are as we expect and so forth. Any time you find it hard to test some code it usually means the code is doing too much, break it out!